# sync fetch eloquent laravel

Tags: laravel, eloquent, fetch, synchronization

i have this array:

```
  $ingredients_alergens = [
    1285 => [ //id from ingredient
      4, //id from alergen
      2
    ]
    1286 => [
      6
    ]
    1287 => [
      1
    ]
    1288 => [
      9
    ]
  ]
```

and i want make a massive sync similar to this:

```
$ingredient->alergens()->sync([1,3,8]);
```

but with all the array. I want make a únic sync/upsert/something for a full list and don't do query to query. Because i have arrays/jsons from more than a thousand redords.

Are there any way to build a massive sync (into single query, like an upsert) into eloquent laravel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have many `Ingredient`s (1285, 1286, 1287, 1288), so you'd need to get all of them first and then, for each of them, sync the relationship.

You could do it with these 2 lines using your `$ingredients_alergens` variable:

```php
$ingredients_alergens = [
    1285 => [4, 2],
    1286 => [6],
    1287 => [1],
    1288 => [9],
];

Ingredient::findMany(array_keys($ingredients_alergens)) // findMany([1285, 1286, 1287, 1288])
    ->each(fn(Ingredient $i) => $i->alergens()->sync($ingredient_alergens[$i->id]));
```

If you do not want `sync` to delete existing alergens. (For example, you just want to add alergen 9 to ingredient 1288), use `syncWithoutDetaching()` instead of `sync()`.

Comment: Sorry, I may not have explained myself enought well. I want to be able to do it with a single query (so as not to overload the database). With your way I am doing the sync to each entity separately.

Comment: In that case, you can't. Specially not with a complicated operation like syncing many to many relationships. Eloquent works on a per-model basis.